# require js creating with marionette

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am getting errors in console. Can you help me fix it.

I have included `requirejs` and necessary backbone libraries.

[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/bahefuracehe/15/edit)

My code

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    backbone : '//jashkenas.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js',
    underscore : '//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js',
    jquery : '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
    marionette : 'http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.min.js'
  },
  shim : {
    jquery : {
      exports : 'jQuery'
    },
    underscore : {
      exports : '_'
    },
    backbone : {
      deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    marionette : {
      deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
      exports : 'Marionette'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: which errors are you concerned with? i saw image link errors, but that's on you to get the right image link as i have no idea what you're trying to show

Comment: Abot the mismatch errors...thanks for your rePly

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to add backbone,jquery and other library's script tag in html, since you already include them using requirejs api.
Second, it's recommended that you put your define code in a single file, or you should give it a name.

More info, see here: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

> Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API.
> **Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have define() calls in them.**
>
> **If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes named modules,** and that an anonymous module that will have the same
> name as one of the modules in that file is not loaded.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in jsbin its so much confusing

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you tell me what did you modify...and sill json not coming in handlebars